# Restoring inapp purchased items in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm trying to give the user the ability to restore his inapp purchased items from my application.

I'm using the following code:

```
     ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() 
    {




        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

                Log.d("TEST", "mService ready to go!");
                checkownedItems();    

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               mService = null;  

        }
    };




    public void checkownedItems()
    {
        try
        {
             String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MY_KEY";
        //    Log.d("getPackageName ", "Items Owned: " + getPackageName());
            Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

            if(ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0)
            {


                ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");

                //ownedSkus.toArray();
                ownedSkus.add("test");

                for (int n=0;n<ownedSkus.size();n++)
                   {
                            Log.d("Items: ", "Items: " + ownedSkus.get(n));

                   }  

                ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
                String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");
                //Log.d("Items Owned: ", "Items Owned: " + ownedSkus.size()); toast
                Log.d("Data List: ", "Data List: " + purchaseDataList.size());
                Log.d("signature List: ", "signature List: " + signatureList);
                Log.d("continuation Token: ", "continuation Token: " + continuationToken);
                if(purchaseDataList.size() > 0)
                {
                    //Item(s) owned
                     Log.d("purchaseDataList: ", "purchaseDataList: " + purchaseDataList.size());
                    for(int i=0; i<purchaseDataList.size(); ++i)
                    {






                        String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);


 /*         String xx =          ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN"); 

                            Log.d(TAG, "INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN: " + xx);
                                */

                                        Log.d(TAG, "Item_SKU: " + "consume");
                                        String bookpdf = "http://www.mybook.com/"+sku+ ".pdf";


                                    String Bookvalue=   sku.substring(sku.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

                                        downloadAndEncrypt(bookpdf,Bookvalue + ".pdf");
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Item_SKU-Download: "
                                                + "Download Complete");
                                        Log.d("OWNED_ITEMS_FINAL_SIZE","OWNED_ITEMS_FINAL_SIZE: " + ownedItems.size() );
                                        Log.d("OWNED_ITEMS_FINAL_LIST","OWNED_ITEMS_FINAL_LIST: " + ownedItems.keySet()); 
                                        Log.d("ownedSkus1","ownedSkus1: " + ownedSkus.size() );
                                        Log.d("ownedSkus2","ownedSkus2: " + ownedSkus.toString()); 
                                        Log.d("ownedSkus3","ownedSkus3: " + ownedSkus); 

                                        //Log.d("testtt","testtt " + "INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST".length());



                                    /*  String value = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
                                        Log.d("my_test","my_test: " + value); */

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Item(s) not owned


                    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

                    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
                    {


                        @Override
                        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             if(!result.isSuccess())
                                {
                                    Log.d("TEST", "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.d("TEST", "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Error checking owned items
            }
        }
        catch(RemoteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mServiceConn != null)
        {
            //unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }
    }
```

Note that I'm using the correct base64EncodedPublicKey key of my application.

The problem now is the above code only returns the first inapp item purchased from my application. I tried much everything possible with that piece of code, and it always returns only the first item when trying to log the output results.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
private void queryUserPurcahses()
{
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener 
   = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
      Inventory inventory) {

      if (result.isFailure()) {
        // handle error here
      }
      else {
            boolean is_purchased_1 = inventory.hasPurchase(product_1_ID);  
            boolean is_purchased_2 = inventory.hasPurchase(product_2_ID);  

      }
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As mentioned below in my comment, I solved the issue.
I didn't test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was consuming the purchased items in my code. What I did I just commented the consumeitem() function, and when I published my apk (it has to be published to return all the purchased items don't know why!) it worked like a charm and restored all my item that I purchased after commenting the consumeitem().

Thank you all.